# Creating one universal legend for many ggplots with unique combinations of a universal factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several barcharts with unique level combinations of one universal factor.
I want to achieve a shared legend between all plots, showing all levels of the factor.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(c=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), x=1:5,  y=runif(5))
df2 <- data.frame(c=c('a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'), x=1:5,  y=runif(5))

dd <- union(df1$c,df2$c) #### combine all factor levels into one string
dd.col <- rainbow(length(dd)) ### some colors, could be anything
names(dd.col)  <- dd #### create a named vector of all factors present in all unified plots


g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = dd.col)
g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = dd.col)
grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

Here is one solution, which produces the desired output, but it is clumsy, and not very practical for my data set (many plots, many levels)

```
df3 <- data.frame(c=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), x=1:7,  y=runif(7))
g3 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = dd.col) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

library(cowplot)

leg <- get_legend(g3)
plot_grid(
  plot_grid(g1 + theme(legend.position = "none"),
            g2 + theme(legend.position = "none"), ncol=2),
          leg,
          align = "hv", nrow=2, rel_heights = c(1,0.1))
```

what is a better solution for large datasets with many levels of the grouping factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show all categories in both legends set the `limits` of the scale to include all levels of your factor. And to finally get a shared legend you could use `patchwork`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = c)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = dd.col, limits = dd)

g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = c)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = dd.col, limits = dd)

g1 + g2 + 
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]